# Python Falcon microservice that uses microservice?

Tags: python, rest, falconframework

I'm just getting started with Falcon and I'm trying to do something that I think should be very simple and basic. I simply want one of my services to send a request to another one.

Let me make it even more simple with a tiny code example. Here are two microservices. Service #1 stores a number, and service #2 increments a stored number.

```
class NumberResource:
    def on_post(self, req, resp):
        self.value = req.media.get('value')
        resp.media = {'value': self.value}

    def on_get(self, req, resp):
        resp.media = {'value': self.value}

class NextNumberResource:
    def on_get(self, req, resp):
        sibling = {}
        # TODO sibling = get("/number")
        resp.media = {'value': sibling.value+1}

api = falcon.API()
api.add_route('/number', NumberResource())
api.add_route('/next', NextNumberResource())
```

Now I can store the number 17:

```
curl http://localhost:8000/number -d '{"value":17}'
```

And I can retrieve the stored value:

```
curl http://localhost:8000/number
{"value": 17}
```

I want to fill in the TODO line so that I can retrieve the calculated value:

```
curl http://localhost:8000/next
{"value": 18}
```

What's the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be via OOP pattern in Python. An example could be like this (Albeit, it needs more defensive programming + serialization/de-serialization)

```
class SomeLogicHandler():

    myValue #Important to have myValue as class variable and not as instance variable.

    def __init__(self):
        super(SomeLogicHandler, self).__init()
        self.updateMyValue = self._updateMyValue
        self.getMyValue = self._getMyValue

    def _updateMyValue(self, value):
        self.myValue+= value

    def _getMyValue(self):
        return {value: self.myValue}

class ApiRouteHandler(SomeLogicHandler):

    def __init__(self):
        super(ApiRouteHandler, self).__init__()

    def on_post(self, req, resp):
        #post implementation.
        self.updateMyValue(req.media.get('value'))


class ApiRouteHandler2(SomeLogicHandler):

    def __init__(self):
        super(ApiRouteHandler2, self).__init__()

    def on_get(self, req, resp):
        #get implementation.
        resp.body = self.getMyValue()
```

Comment: You are using `SomeLogicHandler` before it is defined.  Does this actually work for you?

Comment: Thanks for the update. I usually decouple all logic handlers into a separate package and import them within API route handlers. I missed mentioning that in my response above. I shall update it. Thanks again.